# Reuse eventhandler in multiple forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using C# with Windows Forms. In several of my forms I have code such as this:

```
public myForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    groupBox1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(groupBox_Paint);
    groupBox2.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(groupBox_Paint);            
}
```

Each of these forms have a `groupBox_Paint` method inside them. However, I would like these forms to reuse this method from one location so I don't have copies of it in different forms. I have tried making the method public static in a form and accessing it from the event handler but I received an error because of the code `this.BackColor` :

> Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer

What would be a good way of doing this? Thank you.

The code for `groupBox_Paint` and associated method is below:

```
public static void groupBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    GroupBox box = sender as GroupBox;
    DrawGroupBox(box, e.Graphics, Color.Black, Color.Black);
}

public static void DrawGroupBox(GroupBox box, Graphics g, Color textColor, Color borderColor)
{
    if (box != null)
    {
        Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(textColor);
        Brush borderBrush = new SolidBrush(borderColor);
        Pen borderPen = new Pen(borderBrush);
        SizeF strSize = g.MeasureString(box.Text, box.Font);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(box.ClientRectangle.X,
                                       box.ClientRectangle.Y + (int)(strSize.Height / 2),
                                       box.ClientRectangle.Width - 1,
                                       box.ClientRectangle.Height - (int)(strSize.Height / 2) - 1);

        // Clear text and border
        g.Clear(this.BackColor);

        // Draw text
        g.DrawString(box.Text, box.Font, textBrush, box.Padding.Left, 0);

        // Drawing Border
        //Left
        g.DrawLine(borderPen, rect.Location, new Point(rect.X, rect.Y + rect.Height));
        //Right
        g.DrawLine(borderPen, new Point(rect.X + rect.Width, rect.Y), new Point(rect.X + rect.Width, rect.Y + rect.Height));
        //Bottom
        g.DrawLine(borderPen, new Point(rect.X, rect.Y + rect.Height), new Point(rect.X + rect.Width, rect.Y + rect.Height));
        //Top1
        g.DrawLine(borderPen, new Point(rect.X, rect.Y), new Point(rect.X + box.Padding.Left, rect.Y));
        //Top2
        g.DrawLine(borderPen, new Point(rect.X + box.Padding.Left + (int)(strSize.Width), rect.Y), new Point(rect.X + rect.Width, rect.Y));
    }
}
```

Comment: Derive your own class from GroupBox, override OnPaint().  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this line

```
g.Clear(this.BackColor);
```

`this` is a reference to an instance of Form, it cannot be used inside a static method. You can pass the background of the form as a parameter.

```
public static void DrawGroupBox(GroupBox box, Graphics g, 
    Color textColor, Color borderColor, Color backgroundColor) 
{
    ...
    // Clear text and border
    g.Clear(backgroundColor);
    ...
}
```

And use it like this

```
private void groupBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    GroupBox box = sender as GroupBox;

    //assuming DrawGroupBox is defined in another class `CommonUtil`
    CommonUtil.DrawGroupBox(box, e.Graphics, Color.Black, Color.Black, this.BackColor);     
}
```

Comment: The code should use a cast, not `as`, i.e. `GroupBox box = (GroupBox)sender;`. Using `as` means you'll pass `null` to `DrawGroupBox()` if the wrong object type is used at some point, and the code will throw `NullReferenceException` at a useless place instead of the much more useful `InvalidCastException` at the place where things actually go wrong. Also, your answer should show how the parameter is used in the `DrawGroupBox()` method, since that's the place where the compiler error actually needs fixing.

Comment: Thx, update my answer. Usually `as` is followed by a null check, which is more elegant than casting in a try clause.

Comment: _"which is more elegant than casting in a try clause"_ -- the only reason to use `as` is if it's a valid scenario for the object to be something other than what you're trying to cast to. If you use `as` defensively, then all that's going to happen is the program will fail to crash when it's supposed to, and will not draw like it's supposed to, and it will be that much harder to figure out what's wrong. I don't recommend using `try`/`catch` with a cast; you _want_ the program to crash if the cast fails, because it means the program isn't working like you expect it to.